# IE11 пользовательский стиль страницы

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Помогите найти решение. Старый сайт корректно отображается на IE8. Появилась необходимость обновить систему на windows10 и c IE11. В IE11 не корректно отображаются цифры, показания температуры и знак цельсия не отображаются в одну строку. Когда в стилях (средства разработчика) отключаю параметр width (по умолчанию 30px), то показания температуры и знак цельсия переходят в одну строку.
Как можно добавить свой стиль для IE11?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добавил файл css в свойствах браузера

[image: Добавил файл css в свойствах браузера]